# Flutter pull down to refresh seems to work but it does not refresh

Tags: flutter, pull-to-refresh

I am a beginner in Flutter and I'm struggling with this problem for quite some time now.

I have made a Flutter app which fetches posts from a wordpress website. Everything works fine, except the pull to refresh. It seems to work (at least the indicator is working), but it doesn't update in the background and I have no clue where the problem could be.

Please take a look to my my posts_list.dart file:

```
import 'package:wordpress_flutter/widgets/refresh_widget.dart';
import '../model/post_entity.dart';
import '../network/wp_api.dart';
import '../widgets/post_list_item.dart';
import '../widgets/refresh_widget.dart';

class PostsList extends StatefulWidget {
  int category = 0;
  PostsList({this.category = 0});
  @override
  _PostsListState createState() => _PostsListState();
}

class _PostsListState extends State<PostsList> {
  final keyRefresh = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
  List<PostEntity> posts = [];

  int page = 0;
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        getData();
      }
    });
  }

  Future getData() async {
    keyRefresh.currentState?.show();
    if (!isLoading) {
      setState(() {
        page++;
        isLoading = true;
      });

      WpApi.getPostsList(category: widget.category, page: page).then((_posts) {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
          posts.addAll(_posts);
        });
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => SizedBox(
        height: 300,
        child: buildList(),
      );

  Widget buildList() => posts.isEmpty
      ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
      : RefreshWidget(
          keyRefresh: keyRefresh,
          onRefresh: getData,
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: posts.length + 1,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              primary: false,
              controller: _scrollController,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                if (index == posts.length) {
                  return _buildProgressIndicator();
                } else {
                  return PostListItem(posts[index]);
                }
              }));

  Widget _buildProgressIndicator() {
    return new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Center(
        child: Visibility(
          visible: isLoading,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the refresh_widget.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RefreshWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> keyRefresh;
  final Widget child;
  final Future Function() onRefresh;

  const RefreshWidget({
    Key key,
    this.keyRefresh,
    @required this.onRefresh,
    @required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RefreshWidgetState createState() => _RefreshWidgetState();
}

class _RefreshWidgetState extends State<RefreshWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      Platform.isAndroid ? buildAndroidList() : buildIOSList();

  Widget buildAndroidList() => RefreshIndicator(
        key: widget.keyRefresh,
        onRefresh: widget.onRefresh,
        child: widget.child,
      );

  Widget buildIOSList() => CustomScrollView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: [
          CupertinoSliverRefreshControl(onRefresh: widget.onRefresh),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: widget.child),
        ],
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely check out the package called [pull_to_refresh](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh). It helps out a lot.

From my observation, your issue could be that you add all your posts that you get to the `posts` list. Instead, try replacing the list by the incoming list. Your way would only work for the first time, since initially the `posts` list is empty. However, the next time, it just adds another list of posts to all the posts you got from `initState`.

```dart
Future getData() async {
    keyRefresh.currentState?.show();
    if (!isLoading) {
      setState(() {
        page++;
        isLoading = true;
      });

      WpApi.getPostsList(category: widget.category, page: page).then((_posts) {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
          posts = _posts
        });
      });
    }
  }
```